# Стратегия чтения сокета

Tags: сокеты

Если есть протокол передачи данных(к примеру - первые 2 бита определяют, что это наш пакет, следующие 4 указывают длинну пакета, оставшиеся - данные), какой подход чтения из сокета лучше применять:

- читаем 2+4 байта, разбираем, дочитываем сколько нужно, или
- вычитываем все что есть из сокета, после чего в байтовом массиве ищем начало нашего сообщения, и повторяем операцию из первого пункта

Какой подход дает преимущества, и в каких случаях?

Comment: Вообще еще зависит от того, как эти данные сервер посылает.

Comment: Сокет посылает сообщения этим же протоколом

Comment: Что значит "из сокета"? Что за сокет? Если обмен по tcp, то лучше считать 2+4, а затем столько, сколько нужно, ибо tcp представляет из себя трубу и "всё, что есть" для tcp понятие несколько странное. Если сокеты другие, то решение может быть другим

Answer (score 3):

[[@Антон Феоктистов](/users/357/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)](/users/357/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), первый вариант в примитивной реализации проще, но второй эффективней.

Думаю, что речь идет о TCP сокетах, с ними 
в *nix часто удобно связать с сокетом `FILE *` (используя функцию `fdopen`) и спокойно читать по частям, предоставив всю работу с буферизацией `libio`.

Аналогично можно поступить для записи в тот же сокет, связав с ним еще один `FILE *` на запись, хотя это сильно зависит от структур данных, которые вы отсылаете. Если у Вас для передачи сразу готов достаточно большой массив, то можно сразу отсылать вызовом `send()` и не делать `FILE` для отсылки данных. А если данные создаются и форматируются в разных функциях программы, то использование `FILE` весьма удобно.

При работе с `FILE`, соединенном с дескриптором сокета, нужно помнить, что при fclose дескриптор сокета будет закрыт. Если нужно, например, закрыть сокет для записи (тем самым мы сигнализируем нашему визави, что данные больше посылаться не будут), оставив открытым на чтение, то можно поступить так

```
FILE *in = fdopen(sockfd, "r"),
     *out = fdopen(dup(sockfd), "w");
....
// работаем с in, out
fclose(out);               // вот здесь мы закрыли дубликат sockfd
shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR); // сделаем это же только для "половинки" исходного сокета
// продолжаем работать с in
```

Однако, в виндоус эта схема не работает, поскольку в ней для сокетов применимы только `send()` и `recv()`, а `read` и `write`, используемые в операциях с `FILE` не работают.

Возможно, оптимальным приемом для переносимой программы будет написание собственной простой версии необходимых для конкретной задачи операций с сокетом и привязанным к нему буфером, аналогичных операциям с FILE.

Плюсом такого подхода будет упрощение реализации таймаута (вся работа с сигналами и таймером инкапсулируется в файле с кодом Ваших собственных операций).

Вообще-то, тут важно не усложнять, не гнаться за излишней универсальностью, скорее сосредоточиться на конкретной задаче. Впоследствии такой код будет Вашим собственным отличным шаблоном  для следующей, похожей задачи.

Резюмируя и возвращаясь к ответу непосредственно на вопрос, можно сказать, что из рассматриваемых в вопросе, второй вариант лучше (гибче, эффективней), но для простых программ, возможно, сложноват.